# Support of SCTP on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: compiling

I am developing an application that will make use of some of the [SCTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol) (Stream Control Transmission Protocol) APIs like `sctp_bindx`, `sctp_connectx` etc.

My kernel version is 3.13.0-49-generic.

If I try to compile my code, I get

```
fatal error: netinet/sctp.h: no such file or directory.
```

If I install `lksctp-tools` package then my code gets compiled.

Can I use the APIs without installing any `libsctp` library ? Since I read that SCTP is supported by kenel versions > 2.1

Answer (score 5):

At least for 14.04, `apt-file` says:

```
[romano:~] % apt-file search netinet/sctp.h
libsctp-dev: /usr/include/netinet/sctp.h
```

so to compile any code that `#include`s the file `sctp.h` you need to install the package `libsctp-dev` and its dependences via

```
sudo apt-get install libsctp-dev
```

If you want to do this at low level (kernel direct syscall access etc.) you should probably replicate all the boilerplate code of the library --- why would you do that? You don't do that with `sys_open()` and friend, you use `libc` to get these nicely wrapped up.

Get more info about this (and any) package with `apt show libsctp-dev`.

Comment: Do you have any information about libsctp ? it comes under which license ?

Comment: No idea.... Grab the sources and look. It's in the main repo, so probably GPL or LGPL. Any program in Linux will be linked against tens of libraries like that.... But IANAL and you should check your case.

Answer (score 0):

To install this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
apt-get install libsctp-dev
```